# ByteBuffer in Python - Alternative to Scala

Tags: python-3.x, scala, hash, bytebuffer

I have a piece of code in Scala which I need to convert into Python:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

val string = Array(28087,33,580,21,"a2aa639d-6b3a-4844-b343-8d1b335af21b",9,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1).mkString("|")
val digester = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
val hashBytes = digester.digest(string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))

val bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(java.lang.Long.BYTES)
bb.put(hashBytes, 0, java.lang.Long.BYTES)
bb.flip()
bb.getLong()
```

So, this gives the output `-3586932978655362506`. Now I am trying to convert this in Python to get the same results

```
import hashlib
s = "28087|33|580|21|a2aa639d-6b3a-4844-b343-8d1b335af21b|9|1|1|0|1|0|0|0|1"
hashBytes = hashlib.sha1(bytearray(s, 'utf-8')).digest()

### need the code for bytebuffer ###
```

For bytebuffer in Python, I am trying to use `PyByteBuffer` but not able to find the corresponding functionality. Any help in this regard?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes